# Resize ElementHost to size of the hosted XAML UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like an expanding panel in my Windows Forms app. I was having a look to see if this would be possible using the WPF Expander control. I've created a Xaml UserControl where I've inherited from Expander rather than UserControl. I have a trigger on the Expander for setting it's size.

Is it possible to change the height of the ElementHost to reflect the change in the size of the child? Or would I just be better off creating an expanding Panel in Windows Forms?

I'm using C# .Net 3.5.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You need to override `MeasureOverride` in your outermost WPF control, convert the size from WPF coordinates to device coordinates, and update `ElementHost.Size`.

Since you are already subclassing `Expander`:

1. Override the `MeasureOverride` method
2. After the measurement is calculated, use `PresentationSource.From(visual).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(point)` to get the device coordinates
3. Update `ElementHost.Size`.

Your `Expander` subclass instance will need a pointer to `ElementHost` to do this.

A more general solution would be to create a new class to handle the synchronization.  It would subclass `FrameworkElement` and be the direct child of `ElementHost`.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are *inheriting* from Expander vs. just *using* an Expander in your UI?

If you set up the H/V Alignment properties of the Expander, you should be able to get most standard sizing behaviors without having size triggers.  From my experience, the content portion of the Expander automatically sizes to fit.

If you're trying to completely remove the header part, then you might look at making your own ControlTemplate for the Expander.