# Auto size ElementHost to its content

Tags: wpf, winforms, elementhost

I have a small WPF control that has a TextBlock with TextWrapping set to Wrap. I am trying to host this in an existing WinForms application. I have the ElementHost docked to the top of the form, and I would like to size the height of the ElementHost based on the height that the TextBlock require. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

The resizing mechanism of WinForms is different from WPF's.

Have you tried setting the [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.autosize.aspx) property of the ElementHost to true?

Comment: That was my first thought, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Did you have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086184/resize-elementhost-to-size-of-the-hosted-xmal-usercontrol

Comment: Setting the `AutoSize` property for the `ElementHost` as well as the `AutoSize` for the control that contains the `ElementHost`, in my case a `Form`, works for me.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Thanks, that works like a charm, in my case with the `ElementHost` contained within a `Panel`

Comment: @MikedeKlerk in my case im setting "AutoSize" to both the "ElementHost" and "Form" Onloading window in first time Form size greater then my control size

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://www.wenda.io/questions/2722326/resize-form-based-on-elementhost-size.html)

this is code from the link above:

```
public System.Windows.Size GetElementPixelSize(UIElement element) 
{ 
    Matrix transformToDevice; 
    var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(element);
    if (source != null)
        transformToDevice = source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;
    else     
        using (var Hwndsource = new HwndSource(new HwndSourceParameters()))
            transformToDevice = Hwndsource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;


    if (element.DesiredSize == new System.Windows.Size()) 
        element.Measure(new System.Windows.Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); 

    return (System.Windows.Size)transformToDevice.Transform((Vector)element.DesiredSize); 
}
```